# Using Conditional Probability to find Probability of Events

Tags: probability

If probability of $A$ given $B$ is $\frac13$: $P(A\mid B)=\frac13$ and the probability of $B$ given $A$ is $\frac12$: $P(B\mid A)=\frac12$, and $P(A)+P(B)=1$, find $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

I assume we just need to find the probability of the intersection of $A$ and $B$ and then we can just use the conditional probability formula to find $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. But I am not sure how to find the intersection.

Comment: Maybe play around with formulas.  $\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)=1/3$. So $\Pr(B)=3\Pr(A\cap B)$. Do something similar with $\Pr(B\mid A)$ and it should be about over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(B\mid A)=\cfrac{\color{red}{P(A\cap B)}}{P(A)}\tag{1}$$

$$P(A\mid B)=\cfrac{\color{red}{P(A\cap B)}}{P(B)}\tag{2}$$

Equate $(1)$ and $(2)$ for the parts marked red.

After substituting values in you will get $$2P(B)-3P(A)=0\tag{A}$$
and the other equation you already have $$2P(B) + 2P(A)=2\tag{B}$$

Now find $(B)$-$(A)$ and solve the simultaneous equations. To get $$5P(A)=2\implies P(A)=\color{blue}{\frac25}$$ & $$P(B)=1-\frac25 =\color{blue}{\frac35}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Bayes theorem tells us

$$P(A|B)\times P(B)=P(B|A)\times P(A)$$

Together with $P(A)+P(B)=1$, you can simply determine $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ because
$P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$ are given.

The result is $P(B)=0.6$ , $P(A)=0.4$

Comment: Oh yes, I see it now, thankyou for the help!